# Input box isn't appearing in the hoverover area.

Tags: html, css, stylesheet

I'm creating a list of items inside of a div.
Each item has an img and some description of it.

I have it so that when you hover over the picture you can place a certain quantity that you'd like.

However, my submit box is appearing outside of the hoverbox area.

Here is a picture of how I'd like it to look:
[image]

Here is a picture of how it looks now:
[image]

I've been messing around with the css but I just can't get it to style the way I want.

Here is a small html snippet and the css that goes along with the hover

html:

```
<div id="content_wrap">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="images/menu/item1.png">
                <span class="hoverBox">
                   <p>QTY = </p>
                   <input type="text"/>
                </span>
            </div>
            <p class="sushi_info">"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. "</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="images/menu/item2.png">
                <span class="hoverBox">
                   <p>QTY = </p>
                   <input type="text"/>
                 </span>
            </div>
            <p class="sushi_info">"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. "</p>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.hoverBox{
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #F8F8F8;
    border: 5px solid #DFDFDF;
    color: #717171;
    font-size: 13px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    line-height: 30px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    display:none;
    top:-130px;
    padding:20px;
    width:150px;
    height:20px;
}

.hoverBox:after{
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    bottom:-10px;
    width:10px;
    height:10px;
    border-bottom:5px solid #dfdfdf;
    border-right:5px solid #dfdfdf;
    background:#f8f8f8;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-5px;
    -moz-transform:rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(45deg);
    transform:rotate(45deg);
}

div.item{
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    cursor:pointer;
}

div.item:hover span{
    display:block;
}

p{
width:30%;
height:100%;
}
```

Any ideas on what I could do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `position:absolute` on the hoverbox and position it nicely over the underlying element. The `li` has to have `position:relative` though. You can then apply all sorts of styling effects including a background transparency to achieve your result. The `input` should also be inside the `p` or use `label` instead of `p`.

See if this example can help: http://jsfiddle.net/CQjzg/1/

Note: I replace the img with a div to simulate your content.

Answer (score 0):

I believe its do to the

tags... It pushed out the  I would wrap them inside another DIV or